# How to Upload multiple images of 1 product using System > Import/Export > Dataflow - Profiles

Tags: magento-1.7, import, image, dataflow

I want to upload multiple images of 1 product using System > Import/Export > Dataflow - Profiles,

My question is about

```
System > Import/Export > Dataflow - Profiles
```

Not About

```
System > Import/Export > Import
```

I have uploaded a product with single image, but don't know what csv format to use for multiple image of one product ?

Please Help, Regards.

Comment: I have the same question. did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: @Harry No, Bro, But I managed to import product along with multiple images using 
System > Import/Export > Import Option

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the product converted used in the dataflow module `Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product` it would appear that it can only deal with one product image :(

```
foreach ($product->getMediaAttributes() as $mediaAttributeCode => $mediaAttribute) {
    if (isset($importData[$mediaAttributeCode])) {
        $file = trim($importData[$mediaAttributeCode]);
        if (!empty($file) && !$mediaGalleryBackendModel->getImage($product, $file)) {
            $arrayToMassAdd[] = array('file' => trim($file), 'mediaAttribute' => $mediaAttributeCode);
        }
    }
}
```

This code seems to simply set a single file that later gets added to the product data. What you could do would be to rewrite this class and update the code to deal with more than one product image.

Something like the following may point you in the right direction.

```
$allImages = explode(',', $importData['media_gallery']);
foreach ($allImages as $file) {
    $imagesToAdd[] = array('file' => trim($file));
}
$mediaGalleryBackendModel->addImagesWithDifferentMediaAttributes(
    $product,
    $imagesToAdd, Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import',
    false,
    false
);
```